# CSS3 Animation speeds up on browser resize

Tags: css, animation

I have a purely CSS animating ticker that on page load works perfectly. The speed of the animation is working exactly how I want it.

The problem is when you resize the browser. For some reason when you do this the animation speeds up and when the message has gone off the screen it doesn't come back for ages. I think its an issue with calculating widths but unsure how to fix it.

**jsFiddle**
https://jsfiddle.net/79cmwcjw/2/

**CSS / Reduced for Brevity**

```
@keyframes ticker {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible;
  }

  100% {
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  }
}

.inside {
    width: auto !important;
    display: inline-block !important;
    height: 20px !important;
    line-height: 20px;
    white-space: nowrap; 
    padding:0 0 0 100% !important;

    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-name: ticker;
    animation-duration: 20s;
}

.inside a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding:0 200% 0 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: why the 3d translation ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Its what makes it move from left to right

Comment: i know but why the 3d ?

Comment: hehehe not seen a ticker since the early 2000s, but you have a set speed and as you are animating 100% width right to left, if that width changes size, the animation will appear to go faster / slower

Comment: @egr103 You can use `translateX` for that. However, `translate3d` forces GPU rendering, so it will be smoother.

Comment: a {
            display: inline-block;
            padding:0 100% 0 0 !important;
            font-size: 10px;
          }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's caused by `display: inline-block` on `.inside` element. If you remove that, it will work properly. Here's the jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/79cmwcjw/18/

**Update:**
Here's the new fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/79cmwcjw/33/

Basically, you need to add `position: absolute` to the `.inside` element, and remove the padding from the `a` inside.

Comment: only problem here is that as soon as the start of the text gets to the left hand side of the browser it jumps back to the beginning. I need all text  to animate off screen then go back to the start

Comment: Good point. Completely missed that. I updated the answer and fiddle.

Comment: No idea why you're comment has been voted down, the updated fiddle works a treat. Upvoted.

Comment: Probably someone thought that I downvoted their comment/solution, which I didn't. Not a big deal. Happy to help.